# Android, set Toolbar style in theme.xml file

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-theme

I am trying to customize the look of Toolbar in my app.

**Target**
I would like to set the title color and the background color of the Toolbar.
I read about how Theme and Style works, so I was able to try some solutions.
I found out that title color is managed by `app:titleTextColor` property and the background color from the `android:background` attribute.

---

**Premise**
To know how to act it is necessary to know how the style of the widget that we need to modify is managed.

The base Toolbar style is defined in the `Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar` style as below.

```xml
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextColor">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
    <!-- Overrides minimum height in landscape to avoid headline6 and subtitle1 height concerns. -->
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/mtrl_toolbar_default_height</item>
    <item name="maxButtonHeight">@dimen/mtrl_toolbar_default_height</item>
</style>
```

Here the value of `titleTextColor` is set to `?android:attr/textColorPrimary`.

---

So my first attempt was simply to add the ovverride of `android:textColorPrimary` attribute in my app theme.

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

*Result:* This works.

To also set the background I decided to create a custom Toolbar style where to put the background definition, so I changed my theme as below.

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...    
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolbarStyle</item>
</style>
```

```xml
<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

*Result:* This does not works. The `android:background` is applied but the `android:textColorPrimary` not.

Setting the value of `titleTextColor` directly inside `MyToolbarStyle` works.

```xml
<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
    <item name="titleTextColor">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

I also tried to set the toolbar theme where I override the Android `attribute:textColorPrimary`, as below.

```xml
<style name="Base_ToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:theme">@style/Base_ToolbarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="Base_ToolbarTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

*Result:* This does not works too.

Now I am a bit confused from the outcome of my tests.

Why is it not possible to override the `android:textColorPrimary` in the custom style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply a **`style`** you can use (and the `toolbarStyle` attribute applies this style to all the `Toolbar`) the **`style`** attribute:

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
         style="@style/MyToolbarStyle"
```

with:

```
<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
    <item name="titleTextColor">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

because `titleTextColor` is a property defined in the `Toolbar`.

To apply a **theme overlay** you can use the **`android:theme`** attribute:

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:theme="@style/MyToolbarThemeOverlay"
```

with

```
<style name="MyToolbarThemeOverlay">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

because `android:textColorPrimary` is an attribute defined at theme level.

If you want to override a theme attribute directly in a style you have to use the **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute:

```
<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MyToolbarThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified the question by adding an example about theme overlay. The proble is that i define android:textColorPrimary in another theme and set this theme to te Toolbar the things don't work.

Comment: @blow Answer updated. In a style you use materialThemeOverlay instead of android:theme

Comment: How did you find out about this? Where can I find references?

Answer (score 0):

With using the AppCompat Material Toolbar `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`, I have made the following definitions to customize the Toolbar in a theme

Given this toolbar in a layout file:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MyAppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Define a toolbar style in `themes.xml`:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme.Toolbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
    <!-- Add custom stuff here -->
    <item name="android:background" tools:targetApi="l">@color/dark_primary</item>
    <item name="background">@color/dark_primary</item>
</style>
```

And also add the overlay styles in `themes.xml`:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="MyAppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And then apply in app theme:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:toolbarStyle" tools:targetApi="l">@style/MyAppTheme.Toolbar</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyAppTheme.Toolbar</item>
    ...
</style>
```